# Problem in running android activities in qt/qml through QJniObject

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

i am working on a cross-platform mobile application using qt/qml, and it has a fingerprint authentication, i've decided that i will deal with the authentication part natively, for the android app i am trying to call a java activity (that contain the authentication prompt) through QJniObject features, i've tried many times with no hope

here is the source code of my simple trial ,

**MainActivity.java**

```
package ScytheStudio;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricManager;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public String showFingerPrint(){
        BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
        BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;

        BiometricManager biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this);

        Executor executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(MainActivity.this,executor,new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback(){});


        promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder().setTitle("Hello")
                .setDescription("useFingerPrint to login").setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true).build();

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);

        return "";

        }
}
```

**backedn.cpp**

```
#include "backedn.h"


backedn::backedn(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{

}

void backedn::testFn()
{
    if(QJniObject::isClassAvailable("ScytheStudio/MainActivity")) {

          runApplication("android/src/ScytheStudio","MainActivity");

    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "SOME JAVA CLASS UNAVAIABLE!";
    }
}

void backedn::runApplication(const QString &packageName, const QString &className)
{
    qDebug() << "Start app: " <<packageName <<", "<<className;
    QJniObject activity = QJniObject(QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context());   //activity is valid

    if ( activity.isValid() )
    {
        // Equivalent to Jave code: 'Intent intent = new Intent();'
        QJniObject intent("android/content/Intent","()V");

        if ( intent.isValid() )
        {
            QJniObject jPackageName = QJniObject::fromString(packageName);
            QJniObject jClassName = QJniObject::fromString(className);

            if ( jPackageName.isValid() && jClassName.isValid() )
            {
                qDebug() << "Valid True";

                // Equivalent to Jave code: 'intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings");'
                intent.callObjectMethod("setClassName",
                                        "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",
                                        jPackageName.object<jstring>(),jClassName.object<jstring>());

                    qDebug() << "phase 3";

                jint flag = QJniObject::getStaticField<jint>(
                            "android/content/Intent",
                            "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK");

                intent.callObjectMethod("setFlags", "(I)V",flag);
                qDebug() << "phase 4";
                // Equivalent to Jave code: 'startActivity(intent);'
                QJniEnvironment env;
                activity.callMethod<void>("startActivity","(Landroid/content/Intent;)V", intent.object<jobject>());

                if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
                    qDebug() << "Intent not found!";
                    env->ExceptionClear(); // TODO: stupid method! Remove this!
                }
            } else {
                qDebug() << "Action is not valid";
            }
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Intent is not valid";
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Activity is not valid";
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import Token 1.0


Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TokenBack{
    id:myclass
    }

    Button{
        text:"hello"
        width:50
        height:50

        onClicked: {
            myclass.testFn()

        }

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.qtproject.example" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_CODE%% --" android:versionName="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_NAME%% --">
    <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <application android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false" android:allowBackup="true" android:fullBackupOnly="false">
        <activity android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_ARGUMENTS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="minimal"/>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".android.src.ScytheStudio.MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --" android:screenOrientation="unspecified">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="gudamechi"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Output**

```
D libgudamechi_arm64-v8a.so: Start app:  "android/src/ScytheStudio" ,  "MainActivity"
D libgudamechi_arm64-v8a.so: Valid True
D libgudamechi_arm64-v8a.so: phase 3
W System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/content/Intent;.setFlags(I)V"
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:622)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W System.err:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
D libgudamechi_arm64-v8a.so: phase 4
I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:404494513
W System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {android/src/ScytheStudio/MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
W System.err:   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2067)
W System.err:   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1729)
W System.err:   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5436)
W System.err:   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5394)
W System.err:   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5780)
W System.err:   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5733)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:622)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:25)
W System.err:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
I project.exampl: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=480 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
W libEGL  : EGLNativeWindowType 0x7415128010 disconnect failed
```

**Project Tree**

```
MyQtProject/
├─ MyQtProject.pro
├─ Headers/
├─ Sources/
├─ Resources/
├─ Other files/
│  ├─ android/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  │  ├─ ScytheStudio/
│  │  │  │  ├─ MainActivity.java
```

[Project tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAUFC.png)

Comment: The first error is obvious: There is no such `setFlags` method. There is only [one that returns the Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setFlags(int)).

Comment: For the second question: It is very unusual that `android.src` appears in your class name. What does your directory tree look like?

Comment: thank you for your help, it is as follows: 

MyQtProject/
├─ MyQtProject.pro
├─ Headers/
├─ Sources/
├─ Resources/
├─ Other files/
│  ├─ android/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  │  ├─ ScytheStudio/
│  │  │  │  ├─ MainActivity.java

Comment: That's unreadable in a comment, mate. Edit your question.

Comment: sorry, check the question again

Comment: Right. If I read that correctly, the name of your Activity class is `ScytheStudio.MainActivity` without the `android.src` prefix. Although in a regular Android application that would be hosted under `android/src/java` but I do not know how Qt handles these things.

Comment: thank you for your effort, i've modified `runApplication` function to be : `runApplication("ScytheStudio","MainActivity"); `

and modified the activity name in the manifiest to be : – 
`<activity android:name=".ScytheStudio.MainActivity"`

and still got the same error

Comment: You probably ought to remove the dot. [*However, if the first character in the name value is a period, the app's namespace (from the module-level build.gradle file's namespace property) is prefixed to the name.*](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

Comment: did you find solution to this issue ? If yes, please share the answer.